# Informatica Source Qualifier not working from Windows ODBC data source (system DSN) from Excel xlsx file

Tags: import, odbc, excel, informatica

**Reference:**

https://community.informatica.com/message/62128

**Windows ODBC Workflow:**

Windows > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Data Sources (ODBC) > click "System DSN" menu > click "Add" > choose "Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xlsx) >

Data Source Name: "aaaaaaaaa"

Version: Excel 12.0

click "Select Workbook" button > choose xlsx file

**Informatica PowerCenter Designer Workflow:**

Sources > Import from Database >

ODBC Data Source: "aaaaaaaaa"

click "Connect" button > the button's name changes to "Re-Connect"

**Error:**

.. it doesn't seem to find the data in the worksheet ... I have 3 columns with 10 rows of data

[image: "Nothing has been selected to import" error message]

Comment: Is that really the DSN? The reason I ask is that I wonder if it as simple as one too many a's (though I'm sure you would have already checked that).

Comment: Yah, I'm just emulating a database by using Excel, and making it my data source name.  I tried reducing it to 1 "a", and same message.  I tried both xls format and xlsx (open XML) format.  When Informatica PowerCenter Designer connects to the ODBC source (the file), it locks the file.  If I try opening it in Windows, it says it's locked for editing.  But it can't find the tables and columns in "Sheet1".  Seems to be a compatibility issue with Informatica and this ODBC file type.

Comment: Try opening the ODBC connection programatically through something else (e.g. Activestate python and the odbc module, or VBA and DAO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an Excel file as a source you need to define a **named range** containing the cells with data (that's *Step 1* of the instruction you referenced in the question).

All the named ranges found in the file will be shown in the *Select tables* pane. After you select a table (i.e. a range) and click OK, a new source will be created.

---

You can also consider converting the Excel spreadsheet to the CSV format and using simple flat files as a source. If you're in a Windows environment and have have Excel installed, there's a [VBS script](http://jeffkinzer.blogspot.com/2012/06/vbscript-to-convert-excel-to-csv.html) that can help you automate this process.